# Composer alternatives when download a symfony bundle

Tags: git, symfony, github

I would like to know, that in the case when composer can not install a bundle for Symfony, for whatever reason, it is really enough to download the bundle from github, and place that bundle inside the vendors library? Or do I need to tell Symfony to load the bundle inside the AppKernel class?

Because, I tried both and still can not seem to load the application for whatever reason, and I was wandering to what is left to do.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use composer to manage your dependencies, you may use its generated autoloader.

```
// https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/autoload.php#L9
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you manually install a dependency, the autoloader would not be up-to-date. You will have to generate it using the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```